# linq select distinct date from a DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, distinct

I want to fetch distinct date from a DataTable. Currently I'm using the below code:

```
MyDataTable.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "MyDateColumn");
```

This code considers the time too but I don't want the time to be considered. I wrote the below code to select only Date Part but while making the distinct it considers the time too.

```
MyDataTable.AsEnumerable()
      .Select(row => new { MyDateColumn = row.Field<DateTime>("MyDateColumn").ToString("d") }).Distinct();
```

Please help me to select only **distinct date(i.e by ignoring time)**.

Comment: The code you've given should already be fine as it should only be showing the date as a string. Could you give a sample of the results? (I prefer the approach of using the Date property, but even so, this shouldn't be using the time.)

Comment: What are you doing with the results, by the way? It's not obvious that you're assigning them to anything...

Comment: @Jon Skeet ya you are right. My code is working fine! I was checking the wrong dropdown!!! Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `Select`ing the column by just the `Date` property of the column:

```
MyDataTable.AsEnumerable()
      .Select(row => row.Field<DateTime>("MyDateColumn").Date).Distinct();
```